# Spring in production

Tags: spring

What is the best practice to make changes in beans.xml file in production environment?

Lets imagine Hello World application with one Interface and 2 Implementations. After creating jar and running JVM how can we change implementation in beans.xml without opening jar and reassembling it afterwards?

Is it any trick that permits having beans.xml outside the jar, but without knowing the full file-system path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have the XML in a JAR. Your application should be deployed in at least a WAR, which the app server will probably "explode". The folder WEB-INF/classes will be added to the classpath. You can make changes to the exploded XML here and the app server should detect this and reload the app.

### Edit:

If you are using plain Java SE, you can use a system property to pass the location of the XML file. `System.getProperty("property")` in code and `-Dproperty=value` on the command line.

Comment: I don't see anything indicating that this is a Web App.  What about for non-web applications like a batch execution from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

On top of suggestion made by OrangeDog, I would suggest considering leaving the `beans.xml` inside your deployed application AND using the [PropertyOverrideConfigurer mechanism](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-overrideconfigurer).

Configure an override configurer to point to some fixed path outside of the application, something like `/opt/configuration/something/override.properties` would be ideal. If you can't use an absolute path, you can always try to play with `file:../../..` style of paths. Then you can list only the changed values within the `override.properties` file.